# Does the HMAC of symmetric key revealed weakens the encryption?

Tags: hmac

If I reveal the HMAC of encryption key, does it weaken the secrurity of the payload ?

e.g, I would construct following security packet

```
cipher: bf_cbc
IV: initialization vector to the cipher
key-md5:  md5 of the encryption key
crypt-text: encrypted (md5(text) + text)
```

As above shown, does revealing of md5 (or some other hmac) of the key weakens the scheme ?

I would like to specifically catch the case where the keys (encryption to decryption) dont match, as oppose to decrypt the crypt-text with wrong key and then 'discover' that md5(text) dont match the text so declare corrupted security packet.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) algorithms *may* reveal part of their input data, because confidentiality is not part of their root characteristics. In practice, though, HMAC is safe for that. Similarly, a hash function does not reveal much about its input because it would make it more vulnerable to *preimage attacks*, and good hash functions are strong against that.

If you want to use the hash of the key as a key identifier, I suggest having a look at [this previous question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33934/is-leaking-the-hash-of-your-encryption-key-a-security-risk) and its answers.

You appear to encrypt the concatenation of `MD5(text)` and `text`, which looks like a *homemade* MAC. "Homemade" is rarely a good sign. Combining encryption and MAC properly is [not easy](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac). If you really want to define your own format, you should strive to, at least, use an encryption mode which includes a MAC in a well-studied construction; this points at [EAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAX_mode) or [GCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode). (Speaking of which: Blowfish, MD5... it seems that whatever sources you use to know how to do cryptography are a bit dated (15 to 20 years). In computers, 15 years are a lot.)

Comment: thank you for the hint, I did not realize the important diff between MAC and md5/sha1 is the MAC is _keyed_ hash. I will do the Encrypt-then-MAC scheme. I am using openssl library.